# Ajax "Put" request failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, put, form-data

I am trying to make an ajax "PUT" request in my reactjs application. I am trying to send formdata. When I am sending the request, I am getting an error saying "so and so field is required". I have already appended the those fields in my formdata but still I am getting this error.

Here is the format required by my backend to make the request

```
{
    "name": "",
    "dob": null,
    "born_location": "",
    "current_location": "",
    "description": "",
    "father_name": "",
    "mother_name": "",
    "partner_name": "",
    "religion": "",
    "caste": "",
    "occupation": "",
    "education": "",
    "actor": {
        "awards": "",
        "active_from": null,
        "active_till": null
    },
    "politician": {
        "description": "",
        "political_party": "",
        "constituency": "",
        "positions": "",
        "created_by": null
    }
}
```

Here is how I am making formdata

```
 var formData = new FormData()
        var politician_id = this.props.image_reducer.politicianList[this.props.image_reducer.selectedPoliticianRow].person.id

        console.log("id is "+ politician_id)
        var politician =  {
            "description": document.getElementById('description-input').value,
            "political_party": document.getElementById('party-input').value,
            "constituency": document.getElementById('constituency-input').value,
            "positions": document.getElementById('positions-input').value,
        }
        formData.append("name", document.getElementById('name-input').value)
        formData.append("dob", document.getElementById('birth-input').value)
        formData.append("born_location",document.getElementById("birth-location-input").value)
        formData.append("current_location",document.getElementById('current-location-input').value)
        formData.append("description", document.getElementById('description-input').value)
        formData.append("father_name", document.getElementById('father-input').value)
        formData.append("mother_name", document.getElementById('mother-input').value)
        formData.append("partner_name", document.getElementById('name-input').value)
        formData.append("religion", document.getElementById('religion-input').value)
        formData.append("caste", document.getElementById('caste-input').value)
        formData.append("occupation", "politician")
        formData.append("education", document.getElementById('occupation-input').value)
        formData.append("politician", JSON.stringify(politician))
```

And this is how I make "PUT" request

```
var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": url,
        "type": "PUT",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        "credentials": 'include',
        "headers": {
            Authorization: "Token " +token
        },

        "data": formData,


        success: (response, textStatus, jQxhr) => {
            //this.props.tokenAction(response.auth_token);
            console.log("face name addded")
            // this.props.openFileUpload();
            // that.props.uploadProgress();
        }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {

    });
```

And this is the error I am getting

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a validation error coming from your front end code or is this being returned from the back end service? Do you have access to the back end code? Have you tried watching this request in fiddler? I think there is more here to try and diagnose first with more info that we need before anyone can help you. You're asking us to diagnose a black box.

Comment: It is possible that there is a deserialization error on the server side and it is not getting the value. Do you control the system that this is posting to?

Comment: The format is expected is JSON but you're sending it as form data?

Comment: @thepenguinmaster yes

Comment: @Musa how should I send it then?